# post data using nodejs to odoo

Tags: node.js, odoo

I have to get data from web using node js  and post that data to odoo, so data from that web will be automatically post in odoo
I already get data from that web using node js, but my problem is to post it to odoo using node js, anyone please help me, thankyou

odoo 11 in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please post a code snippet of what you have tried so far and where you are failing. Please also view our community guidelines on what topics can be asked here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [odoo-xmlrpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odoo-xmlrpc).

```
var Odoo = require('odoo-xmlrpc');


var odoo = new Odoo({
    url: <insert server URL>,
    port: <insert server Port (by default 80)>,
    db: <insert database name>,
    username: '<insert username>',
    password: '<insert password>'
});

odoo.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log('Connected to Odoo server.');
    var inParams = [];
    inParams.push({'name': 'FFNew Partner'})
    var params = [];
    params.push(inParams);
    odoo.execute_kw('res.partner', 'create', params, function (err, value) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        console.log('Result: ', value);
    });

    // Update product price
    var inParams = [];
    inParams.push([3626]); //id to update
    inParams.push({'name': 'NewFF Partner'})
    var params = [];
    params.push(inParams);
    odoo.execute_kw('res.partner', 'write', params, function (err, value) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        console.log('Result: ', value);
    });
});
```

**Searching and updating a product `fix_price`**:

```
// Update given product price
// First you need to get the corrsesponding database `id`
// Then you will need to call write method to update the price
odoo.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log('Connected to Odoo server.');
    var inParams = [];
    // You well need a criteria to identify the product
    // and if many call `search_read` and check for
    // the product inside the loop

    inParams.push([['name', '=', "Laptop E5023"]]);
    var params = [];
    params.push(inParams);
    odoo.execute_kw('product.product', 'search', params, function (err, value) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        console.log(value);
        var inParams = [];
        // `value` array can contain more than one product id, it depends on 
        // the search criteria
        inParams.push(value);
        inParams.push({'list_price': PRODUCT_PRICE})
        var params = [];
        params.push(inParams);
        odoo.execute_kw('product.product', 'write', params, function (err, value) {
            if (err) { return console.log(err); }
            console.log('Result: ', value);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: but how do I know data will post in Odoo?
I test this code and only give message tat connected to odoo server and Result 6 in node js, but there's nothing happen in my Odoo :(

Comment: If nodejs logs `Result 6`, that mean that the partner was created and his/her id is `6`.

Comment: and then how i post data to field in odoo?

Comment: did you mean change a field value ?

Comment: "I have to get data from web using node js and post that data to odoo, so data from that web will be automatically post in odoo I already get data from that web using node js, but my problem is to post it to odoo using node js"
ah this is my question, tbh your code is help me to connected to odoo, but my problem is to post my data that i get from other web to odoo, so i'm confused how to post data in odoo for example, i want to post data price using node js, do you know how?
btw thankyou so much for helping me, if you dont mind, let me know how i can contact you beside here, thankyou

Comment: After getting data from web you need to post it to Odoo, so you want to update price field value and the `write` method is what you need.Check my edit.

Comment: is that possible for automatic sent data from that web to odoo with this?

Comment: anyways, everytime i tried thsi code, after @connected to odoo server". it said "Error XMLRPC fault : one of record you are trying modify has already been delete"